# What is the most efficient way to store n generic strings with given dimension "dim" read from a text file?

Tags: c

I am almost new to C programming and I want to know what is the best way to store strings (I don't know **in advance** how many strings I will read, it could be sometimes 10 strings or other times 99, so a variable number of strings, depending from the input text file) read from a text file (each line has one and only one string and all strings have the same length). I have some ideas like using a struct or a bi-dimensional array of dynamically allocated number of strings (so by using "malloc" statement) with the same length. Thanks in advance for your suggestions or solutions.

EDIT: I want to create something similar to LinkedList from Java language because when needed I want to print all the stored strings and I want to remove a string from given position.

Comment: The _"most efficient"_ and _"best"_ way may depend on the situation.

Comment: If you allocate an array of pointers, then when it needs to be reallocated, the string targets themselves don't need to be be shuffled around memory. The strings can be different lengths.

Comment: In my case I need to store these strings and, when needed, I want to print all of them. I also want to remove specific strings saved before from this sort of "list", so if I remove a string in middle position I want to link the string before and after that. I want to create something like "LinkedList" of strings from Java language, if you know what I mean.

Comment: You can use a linked list of `struct` which contains linkage members as well as a string pointer.

Comment: For fixed-sized lines 1d array is the best solution.

Comment: @David__00 "each line has one and only one string and all strings have the same length" -->  If a line of input was "abc\n", would you consider its length as 3 or 4?

Comment: To me it sounds like the most efficient way would be to memory map the file (e.g. with `mmap()`) and then treat it as a 2D array of `char` (and not zero terminated strings) in the code that prints them.

Answer (score 0):

> *(each line has one and only one string and all strings have the same
> length)*

If the string has a constant length simply use char flexible array member.

You can simply read line, add null character terminator and repeat until the whole file was read.

Only one malloc and free needed.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t nLines;
    size_t lineLen;
    char text[];
}lineBuff;

lineBuff *readText(FILE *fi, const size_t lineLen)
{
    lineBuff *buff = NULL;
    if(fi)
    {   
        long fileLength;
        if(fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_END)) { /* error handling */}
        fileLength = ftell(fi);
        buff = malloc(sizeof(*buff) + fileLength + fileLength / lineLen);
        if(buff)
        {
            buff -> nLines = fileLength / lineLen;
            buff -> lineLen = lineLen + 1; // it includes null terminating character
            fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);
            for(size_t line = 1; line <= buff -> nLines; line++)
            {
                if(fread(buff -> text + (line - 1) * buff -> lineLen, 1, lineLen, fi) != lineLen) { /* error handling */}
                buff -> text[line * lineLen] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    return buff;
}


char *regNthLine(const lineBuff *buff, const size_t line)
{
    char *result = NULL;

    if(buff && line < buff -> nLines)
    {
        result = (char *)buff -> text + line * buff -> lineLen;
    }
    return result;
}
```

or you can use array pointers:

```
char *getNthLine1(const lineBuff *buff, size_t line)
{
    char *result = NULL;

    if(buff && line < buff -> nLines)
    {
        char (*lineptr)[buff -> lineLen] = (char (*)[buff -> lineLen])buff -> text;
        result = lineptr[line];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good spot

Answer (score 0):

An alternative take on the pointer to C strings (with some tests).

Here you can find a `create_test_file()` function for making the input, and a `read_fixed_size_strings()` which will read all the data in a single block of memory, then setup another piece of memory with the required pointers. Two `free()` are necessary to cleanup.

In the test, I also included how to remove a line, that is removing only the pointer to it. Still, no list, since it's just O(n) with n the number of strings, but only pointers to the strings are moved. Notice that removing a string from the list doesn't free the associated memory.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

bool create_test_file(const char *filename, size_t len_lines, size_t num_lines)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    char *line = malloc(len_lines + 2);
    strcpy(line + len_lines, "\n");
    // Make num_lines lines
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_lines; ++i) {
        // Make random line
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len_lines; ++j) {
            line[j] = 32 + rand() % (126 - 32 + 1);
        }
        // Write it
        fputs(line, f);
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}

char **read_fixed_size_strings(const char *filename, size_t len_lines, size_t *n)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    len_lines += 2; // accomodate also for \n and 0.
    size_t capacity = 16; // Expected number of lines (random guess)
    size_t nread = 0;
    char *data = malloc(capacity * len_lines);
    while (fgets(data + nread * len_lines, len_lines, f)) {
        ++nread;
        if (nread == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            data = realloc(data, capacity * len_lines); // make space for more data
        }
    }
    data = realloc(data, nread * len_lines); // shrink to fit
    fclose(f);
    
    char **lines = malloc(nread * sizeof(char*));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nread; ++i) {
        lines[i] = data + len_lines * i;
    }
    *n = nread;
    return lines;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(1234567890);
    const size_t num_lines = 1234;
    const size_t len_lines = 37;
    //char *filename = tmpnam(NULL);
    char *filename = "test.txt";
    if (!create_test_file(filename, len_lines, num_lines)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t n;
    char **lines = read_fixed_size_strings(filename, len_lines, &n);

    // Print a line on stdout (\n is already included)
    fputs(lines[7], stdout);

    // Remove line 7 (notice that no memory is freed - this can be made way faster)
    size_t line_to_be_removed = 7;
    for (size_t i = line_to_be_removed; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        lines[i] = lines[i + 1];
    }
    --n;

    // Print a line on stdout
    fputs(lines[7], stdout);

    // Free memory
    free(lines[0]);
    free(lines);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of loading the entire file, then allocating an array of pointers to each line. What you do after that is up to you...

This will handle lines of different lengths and 'empty' lines, too...

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen( "test.txt", "rb" );
    if( fp == NULL )
        exit( 1 ); // add error handling

    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    size_t size = ftell( fp );
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );

    char *buf = (char*)malloc( size + 1 ); // add error handling
    fread( buf, size, sizeof buf[0], fp ); // add error handling
    buf[ size ] = '\0';
    fclose( fp );

    int lCnt = 0;
    for( char *cp = buf; ( cp = strstr( cp, "\n" ) ) != NULL; cp++ )
        lCnt++;

    char **pLines = (char**)malloc( lCnt * sizeof(char*) ); // add error handling

    lCnt = 0;
    for( cp = buf; ( cp = strtok( cp, "\r\n" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        pLines[ lCnt++ ] = cp;

    /*
        pLines is now an array of 'lCnt' pointers to the beginning of each (null terminated) line.
    */

    printf( "ALL:\n" );
    for( int i = 0; i < lCnt; i++ )
        printf( "%02d - '%s'\n", i, pLines[ i ] );

    printf( "Removing third line..." );
    pLines[ 2 ] = NULL;

    printf( "Now:\n" );
    for( i = 0; i < lCnt; i++ )
        if( pLines[ i ] )
            printf( "%02d - '%s'\n", i, pLines[ i ] );

    free( pLines );
    free( buf );

    return 0;
}
```